# java.net.ConnectException message:Non HTTP response message: Connection refused in jmeter

Tags: multithreading, jmeter, load-testing

I have a scenario to download zip file from a website.
when trying to hit 100 users with jmeter getting success response for all 100 users,but when I try to do same for 150 users till 74 users got success response,means users downloading zip file without any error,but remaining users got below error as::
Getting sampler result: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js code:Non HTTP response code: java.net.ConnectException message:Non HTTP response message: Connection refused

Request to provide solution for this

Answer (score 1):

This may mean that your server is overloaded or misconfigured and does not allow additional request so rejects them.

Ensure before that you're not hitting a network contention.

Comment: How to resolve this issue. Is there any alternate solution?

Answer (score 0):

**Never include external stuff** (images, banners, videos, fonts, scripts, whatever) **into your load test**. My expectation is that you are being blacklisted by Google due to requesting this `jquery.min.js` with 150 concurrent users from a single IP address (which is not a real life use case)

The solution would be:

1. Go to the [HTTP Request Defaults](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults) configuration element
2. Add the next line to "URLs must match" input:

   ```
   ^((?!google|facebook|pinterest|twimg|doubleclick).)*$
   ```

   This will filter out calls of "embedded" resources from the external servers like `ajax.googleapis.com` and few others (feel free to amend the above regular expression as needed)

   More information: [Excluding Domains from the Load Test](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732519-Excluding-Domains-from-the-Load-Test)

It is also a good idea to add [HTTP Cache Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager) to the test plan as real browsers download scripts, styles, images, etc. but do it **only once**, on subsequent requests the aforementioned resources are being returned from the browser's cache. HTTP Cache Manager makes JMeter to behave like a real browser by simulating browser cache and respecting [Cache-Control](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control) headers.